# Anyone has a link to Rails (2.3.8) RJS Api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

Do any of you know any good reference for the RJS mechanisms in Rails (2.3.8)? I can find a few examples from like 2006/2007 and no actual documentation.

Comment: I think the documentation is in severe disrepair, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API for Rails 2.3.8 is available at http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/

Specifically for RJS, the documenation is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods.html).